# moment.js year/number format with arabic locale

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, date-formatting

I am formatting dates using moment.js with arabic locale (ar_SA) set.

```
moment.locale('ar_SA');
moment([2016,05,01]).format('MMM YYYY');
//output مايو ٢٠١٦
```

I would like to format only the month part using the locale, but the year in english, example: "مايو 2016" (the same as when formatting using the angular filter: | date:'MMM yyyy')

Is there a way to configure moment.js to do this automatically? (instead of splitting the month and year formatting and simply concatenating 2016 to .format('MMM'))

Answer (score 5):

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    months : [
        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
        "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ]
});
```

Source: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/month-names/

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I never did find a solution to this. I opted for a split/manual approach instead:

```
currentDate.format('MMM') + ' ' + currentDate.clone().locale('en').format('YYYY');
```